# Serial COM port not found making exe file using Pyinstaller

Tags: pyinstaller, pyserial

I have project a which includes some python files. I can generate the `exe` file using `pyinstaller`.
But application can't list COM port names and returns NULL. If not with the `exe`, `app.py` file works normally and can lists com ports.
My file structure:
[image]

There're 3 warnings on the console:
Two of them:

```
11511 WARNING: Ignoring /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/IOKit imported from c:\users\nusret\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pyserial-3.5-py3.8.egg\serial\tools\list_ports_osx.py - ctypes imports are only supported using bare filenames
11511  
WARNING: Ignoring /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation 
imported from c:\users\nusret\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pyserial-3.5-py3.8.egg\serial\tools\list_ports_osx.py - ctypes 
imports are only supported using bare filenames
```

I've tried some solutions on the internet. I guess I couldn't solve it because I am not very expert.

Answer (score 0):

It actually found the com ports.
The cause of the error:  I realized when I debugged. Some functions
defined after the **" if *name* == '*main*':
app.run(debug=True, host="0.0.0.0") "** line. Normally when running from the console there was no problem but it was from exe. it worked when I defined the functions after the main line.